# How to create your own wifi network in mac without internet cable

Tags: macos, network, wifi, macbook-pro, airport

I want to create a network in my room with my mac. I have low wifi signal in my room and my ipad cannot detect it but my mac can. However, I am using a retina mac and thus cannot connect the ethernet cable. Is there any way that I could partition my air port to create a network while connected to my home wifi? 
FYI I am using a late 2013 retina macbook pro with the OS X mavericks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't use your Macbook to extend your wireless network in this way. It seems to only be able to connect to an existing Wi-Fi network or create its own. It can't extend an existing Wi-Fi.

Three options are:

1) Purchase a Thunderbird to Ethernet adapter so you can connect the Macbook to the network over ethernet and then share the ethernet connection over wireless.

2) Connect your iPad to your Macbook by USB cable and then share the Wi-Fi connection over "iPhone USB".

3) Share the Wi-Fi connection on your Macbook over "Bluetooth PAN". This last one is probably the most attractive as it doesn't involve using a cable of some sort.

Comment: If I get another airport, will that work?

Comment: Yes, that would work too. An Airport device can be set up to extend an existing wireless network.